# How to deal with constness when the method result is cached?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, getter, memoization

I have a class with a method (getter) that performs some relatively expensive operation, so I want to cache its result. Calling the method does not change behavior of the object, but it needs to store its result in `this`, so it can't be const.

The problem is that I now have another method that is const and I need to invoke my getter. Is there some generally accepted solution to this problem? Should I bypass the constness checking in the getter to make it const, (Coudn't that cause problems with optimizing compiler?) or I have to propagate the non-constness to all methods that use this getter?

Example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    Foo &expensiveGetter() /*const?*/
    {
        if (cachedValue == nullptr) {
            cachedValue = computeTheValue();
        }
        return *cachedValue;
    }

    void myMethod() /* How to make this const? */
    {
        auto &foo = expensiveGetter();
        // etc.
    }

private:
    Foo *cachedValue = nullptr;
}
```

I am looking for something like the [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) in Rust.

Comment: one of my favorite c++ questions to ask a candidate in a job interview who had self identified as 'expert level c++' was = "what does mutable mean?" , never had a correct answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is one of the situations the `mutable` [specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv#mutable_specifier) fits particularly well. When a class member is `mutable`, that member can be changed even if the enclosing class is `const`.

So, if `MyClass::cachedValue` is a `mutable Foo*` instead of a `Foo*`, you can have `const` member functions in `MyClass` that make changes to `cachedValue` and then all calling code can just act on a `const MyClass` as normal.